# Shuffle a list in Minizinc

Tags: minizinc

```
array[1..6] of var 0..1: Path;
include "alldifferent.mzn";
constraint
forall(j in 1..6)(
alldifferent(i in 1..6)(Path[i])
)
```

Iam trying to shuffle a list into minizinc but i want different results every time like with a for all . how can i do it?
print this:

```
Path = array1d(1..6, [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]);
```

Comment: If you let MiniZinc show all solutions (with the -a flag if running from command line), you will get all the 5040 different solutions. Does this not solve your problem? Or do you mean something else by "shuffle"?  By the way you can simply write `all_different(Path)`.

Comment: thank you again for your respond. i do want 6x times shuffle array list with 0,1.
example[ 0,0,0,0,0,1 ]  [ 0,0,0,0,1,0]
             [ 0,0,0,1,0,0] .. and so on...

Comment: Do you mean a random 6x6 matrix of  {0,1} values? Otherwise I don't understand the "6x times shuffle".

Comment: Please be more specific. In you main question to talked about values in the domain 0..5, now you are asking about 0..1 values.

Comment: my apologies! it was a mistake. yes just 0,1

Comment: Sadly the answer is not accepted yet

Answer (score 5):

There are - at least - two approaches for generating a random matrix depending on if you want to generate all possible variables (the first model below using decision values), or if you just want a  "random" random matrix (the second model using built-in random generator). (A third approach would be that you write your own random generator, but this is left as an exercise :-)).

Here is a simple MiniZinc model that generates all the possible 6x6 matrices of {0,1} as decision variables.

```
int: n = 6;
array[1..n,1..n] of var 0..1: x;
solve :: int_search(array1d(x), first_fail, indomain_random) satisfy;

constraint
  true
;

output
[
   if j = 1 then "\n" else " " endif ++
      show(x[i,j])
   | i,j in 1..n        
];
```

Note: The `indomain_random` heuristic generates the solutions in a more "random-like" order.

There is another way of doing this, using the `bernoulli(0.5)` function, which generates randomly 0 or 1 during the creation of the model, i.e. it's not decision variables:

```
int: n = 6;
array[1..n,1..n] of int: x = array2d(1..n,1..n,[ bernoulli(0.5) | i,j in 1..n]);

solve satisfy;

constraint
  true
;

output
[
  if j = 1 then "\n" else " " endif ++
    show(x[i,j])
  | i,j in 1..n        
];
```

Which happens to generate the following matrix:

```
1 1 1 0 0 0
1 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1
0 1 0 0 1 0
1 1 1 1 0 1
0 1 1 1 1 1
```

The drawback of this is that you then have to manually seed the random generator for generating different matrices. This is (according to https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.5.1/en/command_line.html?highlight=random#cmdoption-r ) done with the `--random-seed i` flag (or `-r i`) but this don't work right now on my MiniZinc version.

MiniZinc has quite a few random generators, see more here: https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.5.1/en/lib-stdlib.html?highlight=random#random-number-generator-builtins .

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Amazing! this is what i was looking for! :)

Comment: That's great. If you are happy with my answer, please set it as Accepted.